# How to do Lists in a view model? + dataannotations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I am using asp.net mvc 3, data annotations and auto mapper.

I want to have all my annotations on properties in my view model once the properties pass validation I use auto mapper to map it back to my domain object.

I have a viewmodel that has properties that I want to have a collection of since I want to generate a table from them. I also want to use them later to use as a form to add rows to this table.

So what do I do? How do I take these properties and make a collection of them?

```
public class UserViewModel()
{
    [Required()]
    public string UserName = {get; set;}
    [Required()]
    public string FirstName = {get; set;}
    [Required()]
    public string LastName = {get; set;}
}
```

I want to use these properties to generate my table and be used for a form.

The only thing I can think of is doing this

```
   public class AddUserViewModel()
    {
        [Required()]
        public string UserName = {get; set;}
        [Required()]
        public string FirstName = {get; set;}
        [Required()]
        public string LastName = {get; set;}
    }

   public class UserViewModel()
   {
       public List<User> Users {get; set;}
       public AddUserViewModel {get; set;}

       public UserViewModel()
       {
           Users = new List<Users>();
       }
   }
```

So basically I have it as a separate view model that is enclosed into another viewmodel that contains a list of Users(my domain model)

That way I use my domain model to generate the table and my AddUserViewModel for my adding of users.

Seems kinda redundant so I am not sure if there is a better way.

**Edit**

I have something like this

```
 var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
 List<Users> users=  UserService.GetAllUsers();
 viewModel = Mapper.Map<Users, UserViewModel>(users);
 return View("Index", viewModel);
```

I also tried

```
var viewModel = new UserViewModel();
 List<Users> users=  UserService.GetAllUsers();
 viewModel.AddUserViewModel = Mapper.Map<Users, AddUserViewModel>(users);
 return View("Index", viewModel);
```

**Edit 2**

I have this and it compiles but I get this error

```
        SomeViewModel viewModel = new SomeViewModel ();       
        List<User> users=  userService.GetAllUsers();
        viewModel.UserViewModel = Mapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserViewModel>>(users);
        return View("Index", viewModel);


Trying to map Domain.User to ViewModels.UserViewModel.
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.
```

Comment: I totally don't understand your question neither what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Ya that was a typo. That is corrected now. I am trying to figure out how I can keep using data annotations in the view model but also return a list of my domain objects possibly without duplicating the code twice. Right now everything in the Users object is basically a duplicate of what is in AddUserViewModel(). I could put the annotations in the domain object but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why would you want to return a list of domain objects in your view model? That's not what view models are supposed to be. View models should reference only other view models. So you have a nice `UserViewModel` which represents a user. Now you need to work with multiple users in your view, so either you pass an `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>` or if you need some other properties you design a view model for this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string UserName = { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string FirstName = { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName = { get; set; }
}

public class SomeViewModel
{
    public List<UserViewModel> Users { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and now your controller action might look like this:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    SomeModel model = _repository.GetModel();
    SomeViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<SomeModel, SomeViewModel>(model);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Now inside your view you could simply use a display template for this `Users` property (`Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Users)`) to show a list of them.

---

UPDATE:

After seeing your update here's how to proceed in terms of good practices:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<Users> users = _repository.GetUsers();
    IEnumerable<UserViewModel> usersViewModel = Mapper
        .Map<IEnumerable<Users>, IEnumerable<UserViewModel>>(users);
    return View(usersViewModel);
}
```

I've also used an [AutoMap](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc/blob/master/src/SampleMvc.Web/Mvc/AutoMapAttribute.cs) attribute in a [sample project](https://github.com/darind/samplemvc/) which could simplify your code to this:

```
[AutoMap(typeof(IEnumerable<Users>), typeof(IEnumerable<UserViewModel>))]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    IEnumerable<Users> users = _repository.GetUsers();
    return View(users);
}
```

This attribute will automatically run after the controller action and before the view is rendered and would use AutoMapper to replace the model with the corresponding view model.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Hmm I thought it was bad to have a collection of view models. It is hard to determine what is the correct way is as in this tutorial http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx he is doing sort of what I have

Comment: @chobo2, no it is not bad practice at all to have collections of view models. The example you are referring to uses an `IEnumerable<Product>` which is exactly what I suggested you in the first part of my answer: `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`. In this example `Product` should be considered as a view model. Also you should avoid writing `foreach` loops in your views. You should use display/editor templates. It will make your code much more concise. So you could easily replace the foreach shown in the blog post with a single line in the view: `Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Products)`.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - But is it not his domain object? I mean then you can consider what I said to me my ViewModel(User). I guess diplay/editor templates is a whole new question as I always use foreach.

Comment: @chobo2, the blog post is so much simplified that you cannot actually say whether `Product` is a domain or a view model. He doesn't use any repository to fetch it: it is hardcoded in the controller action so this cannot be a real world example. What the author of the blog post is trying to illustrate here is not domain vs view models, it is ViewData vs strongly typed views. For me everything that is passed to a view should be a view model.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Ok that makes sense. I am wondering if I was to generate a table and need to repeat the rows how would display templates eliminate the foreach loop?

Comment: @chobo2, like this: `<table><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Users) %></table>` and then inside `~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/UserViewModel.ascx` which is strongly typed to `UserViewModel` you simply: `<tr><td><%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.FirstName) %></td></tr>`. Now the display template will be automatically invoked for each element of the Users collection of your model thus freeing you from the burden of writing any loops in your views.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - What is _repository.GetModel(); returning? I don't understand what "SomeModel" would contain inside it.

Comment: @chobo2, it represents your domain model. It's up to you to say what it contains. I can't say this. Maybe an EF object? A POCO? Something else? That's what your business represents. A view model is just a temporary representation of this business model for the specific needs of a given view. It is probably a subset containing only what is necessary for the view. Or a superset of multiple business models. Once again it all depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I am just confused. Right now I have my repository returning a List of Users now I am confused on how to take that and add to convert that into a list of Viewmodels.

Comment: @chobo2, if your repository returns a list of users then you could have a mapping between a `User` and a `UserViewModel` and then simply pass an `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>` to the view. Or if you don't care about view models pass `IEnumerable<User>` to your view and then display it but remember that this would work in simple scenarios but once things get more complicated without using view models you will have hard times.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - I edited my original post to show what I have.

Comment: Darin Dimitrov - Is there any difference if I use List instead? Also I did this SomeViewModel.UserViewModel = //mapping so that I could insert it into the SomeViewModel one.

Comment: @chobo2, take the habit of using the class/interface which is highest in the hierarchy. So for example if you are only going to loop you don't need a list, an `IEnumerable<T>` simply does the job. If on the other hand you need to access the collection by index then use a static Array and finally if you are going to add/remove elements use an `IList<T>`

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - ok I will look into that. What I have compiled but crashes when I run it.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - Ok I forgot to create the map. I am now trying to use the display templates but I don't get it. Like if I take in a collection of UserViewModels I won't have acess to (x => x.Firstname) without looping through it.

Comment: @chobo2, you don't access the FirstName property inside your view. Inside your view you write: `<table><%= Html.DisplayForModel() %></table>` (assuming your view is strongly typed to `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>`). That's all. Then you create another partial view called `~/Views/Home/DisplayTemplates/UserViewModel.ascx` where Home is the name of your controller. This partial view is strongly typed to `UserViewModel`, not `IEnumerable<UserViewModel>` as your main view. And inside this partial you have access to the FirstName property like this: `<%: Model.FirstName %>`.

Comment: @chobo2, I would also recommend you reading more about editor/display templates. Here's a [good article](http://www.dalsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2010/04/26/mvc-2-templates/) which illustrates the basic notions.